# Como que eu crio uma DropDownList para o MVC5 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Olá tenho estou tendo dificuldade em fazer uma Dropdownlist, tenho 3 classes uma Entities para ter relação com o banco, Uma Genero que está associada com a classe Obra.

```
[Table("Generos")]
public class Genero
{
    [Key]
    public int GeneroId { get; set; }

    public string NomeGenero { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public List<Obra> Obras { get; set; }
}
```

```
[Table("Obras")]
public class Obra
{
    [Key]
    public int ObraId { get; set; }

    public string NomeObra { get; set; }

    public string Autor { get; set; }

    public string Editora { get; set; }

    public string DescricaoObra { get; set; }

    public int GeneroId { get; set; }
}
```

Eu não estou conseguindo fazer o DropDownList, tem alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá...

Como tem bem poucas informações na pergunta, vou pressupor algumas coisas, afim de montar um exemplo que possa ser útil pra você.

Vou dar uma sugestão de como você pode criar seu `DropDownList` existem outras formas de criar, mas vou sugerir da forma com que eu faço.

Vou supor que um `Genero` possui várias obras, então seus `models` ficarão assim:

```
[Table("Generos")]
public class Genero
{
    [Key]
    public int GeneroId { get; set; }

    public string NomeGenero { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Obra> Obras { get; set; }
}

[Table("Obras")]
public class Obra
{
    [Key]
    public int ObraId { get; set; }
    public int GeneroId { get; set; }

    public string NomeObra { get; set; }

    public string Autor { get; set; }

    public string Editora { get; set; }

    public string DescricaoObra { get; set; }

    public virtual Genero Genero { get; set; }
}
```

Sendo assim, seu `Create` `Obrascontroller` ficará assim:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
  {
      //Aqui preenche-se uma ViewBag para usar na View
      ViewBag.Generos = db.Generos.ToList();
      return View();
  }
```

E sua `View` de Create ficará assim:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label">Status</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ObraId, ((IEnumerable<Genero>)ViewBag.Generos).Select(option => new SelectListItem
    {
       Text = option.NomeGenero,
       Value = option.GeneroId.ToString(),
       Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.ObraId == option.GeneroId)
    }), "Selecione um Gênero...", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Genero" })
 </div>
```

Fazendo assim, na criação de uma obra você poderá escolher à qual gênero ela pertence.

Comment: Muito Obrigado resolveu, só que na vez de Model.ObraId == option.GeneroId eu coloquei ao contrário option.GeneroId == Model.ObraId dai funcionou

Comment: @PedroHenrique, se a resposta foi útil marque-a como tal.

Comment: Não sei como que faz isso :v

Comment: @PedroHenrique Quando uma resposta atender o que precisa, você pode marcar como resposta, como já fez e também votar como positivo, "cetinha" pra cima ao lado da resposta. Pode fazer isso aos comentários também.